# How to find out what version of SMB is installed on windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, smb

I am using Windows 7 and want to find out if SMB is installed and if so what version.  How can I do this?

I found this article but it doesn't seem to return anything: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and

I have ran the following commands in Powershell as described in the article and have done it for SMB1 and also tried changing it to SMB2

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB1 -Type DWORD -Value 1 –Force
```

Entries have been created in regedit:

[image]

but when I run this command which is meant to detect a version it just returns nothing and just moves to another line in the powershell window:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
```

[image]

If the reason it is not showing is because it is not installed then how can I install it for windows 7?

Thanks

Comment: Samba != SMB. Not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: You're looking to detect what protocol versions the Microsoft SMB server supports on the local machine, right?  And, despite the title and tag, nothing to do with Samba, an alternative implementation of SMB?

Answer (score 0):

SMB is a protocol for file sharing.
This is a Microsoft protocol, the windows SMB version number is not what you are looking for, what you are looking for is the features that your SMB version is supporting.
On your platform (win 7), SMB3 is not supported (one of the main features is encryption).

About other machines there are several companies that implements this protocol, (SAMBA, visuality Systems, ryussi etc.) and in their services you can look for the version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\ | ? 
{$_.Name -like "*Para*"}
```

That should output the values for SMB1 and SMB2 which you are setting with the `Set-ItemProperty`.